# Stacking Imgs/Video vertically

Tags: html, css

I have code to center my images (and eventually videos) like I want inside a div, but I am trying to get the images to stack vertically in a column.

It works if the space is confined enough, but I want it to work all the time. What can I do? Here is my codepen:

```
div{
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 172vh;
}

img{
    height: 50%;
}
```

https://codepen.io/thejaredmosley/pen/OJPVqBa

Comment: Flexbox? Wrap it in a container set to `display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below:

```css
div {
    ....
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: So I was working with old code, and I forgot that in my client side javascript that I was setting the display style to 'block' which was overwriting all my css styling. Your comment helped me figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it with the `display:block` CSS property.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Give this CSS to your image and your image will get full-width space and will come in a stack.

So for Image, add this property:

```
img{
    display:block;
}
```